# How can I contribute to jQuery UI on GitHub?

Tags: jquery-ui, github

I developed a new feature for jQuery UI, but I don't understand where to find the files in their repository.

I changed https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js and https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

but there is no file called jquery-ui.js, jquery-ui.min.js or jquery-ui.css in their repository.

Answer (score 0):

The files you modified are not the sources of jquery but the artifacts produced by a build.

If you want to add a new feature, get the code here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui and read instructions.

Comment: You are linking to jquery not to jquery-ui

Comment: Sorry, just fixed the link. But the general idea is the same.